# Powershell scripting check and change location help needed

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have written the following script:

```
clear-host

## Step 1 (Creating 2 command line variables)
##########################################################################################################################
Clear-Host
$WorkingDirectory = $ARGS[0]
$DirectoryName = $ARGS[1]

##Step 2 (Check if variables are empty and get user input if necessary)
##########################################################################################################################

if ("$WorkingDirectory" -eq "")
    { 
      Write-Warning "Parameter Required"

     $WorkingDirectory = Read-Host "Enter the absolute path to working directory "
     }

if ("$DirectoryName" -eq "")
    {
     Write-Warning "Paramater Required"

      $DirectoryName = Read-Host "Enter a directory name to search for in $WorkingDirectory "
    }


for ($i=0; $i -le 2; $i++) {write-host ""} # to print 2 blank lines using for loop

##Step 3 (Test to see if PWD is equal to $WorkingDirectory and if not move the location )
##########################################################################################################################


if ("$PWD" -ne "$WorkinDirectory")

    {

      write-host "You are not in the < $WorkingDirectory > . Do you wish to move? Press CTRL+C to exit or wait"

      write-host ""

      pause 

     Set-Location -Path $WorkingDirectory

     }

##Step 4 (Test to see the directory exists in the working directory or not )
##########################################################################################################################

if((Test-Path $DirectoryName) -ne "True")

    {

      write-host "Directory $DirectoryName does not exist"

    }
```

The problem I am facing at step 3. It should check my present location with the $WorkingDirectory variable, if they are not same then the location will be changed. But the problem is even if I am at the same location as the $WorkingDirectory it is still giving me the warning message. how to solve that

Comment: `$pwd` seems to be a structure with one member, `Path`. Try your comparison with `$pwd.path` rather than just `$pwd`.

Comment: same thing is happening. with $PWD.PATH

Comment: OK, now fix the typo that I've just spotted - you're comparing against `$WorkinDirectory`, but you earlier created `$WorkingDirectory`.

Comment: after changing the typo the problem is still there.

Comment: after restarting the session it worked. thanks a lot jeff